# Spark saveAsTextFile with file extension

Tags: apache-spark

I want to partition my results and save them as a CSV file into a specified location. However, I didn't find any option to specify the file format using the below code. All the files are created with the format part-000**. How can I specify the required file format here?

```
records.repartition(partitionNum).saveAsTextFile(path)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```scala
df.coalesce(1).write.option("header",true).csv(path)
```

this path it will be a folder, and it must not be exists, and you can't generate specify csv file. But you can change the hdfs file name by hadoop api(contains in spark).

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._
val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
val file = fs.globStatus(new Path(s"$path/part*"))(0).getPath().getName()
val result:Boolean = fs.rename(new Path(s"$path/$file"), new Path(s"$hdfsFolder/${fileName}"))
```

Comment: I'm writing the files to the S3 location. Is it like the files will be renamed on HDFS before moving the files to s3?

Comment: @RajashreeGr Sorry, I don't know muck about S3. It by moving files to rename.